# How can i use duckduckgo bangs with vimium?

Tags: google-chrome, duckduckgo, vimium

I'm using chrome with the extension **vimium** and set **duckduckgo** as my default search engine.It's really useful to get search results with **duckduckgo bangs**.But I can't use that through vimium's **vomnibar**.Is it possible to combine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to Vimium settings
2. Inside "Custom search engines" text box, uncomment the line
   containing duckduckgo mapping by removing the leading hashtag:

```
  d: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%s DuckDuckGo
```

3. Save changes
4. Now open vomnibar and type `d` followed by a space.  This will
   trigger
   duckduckgo autocompletion.